# angular 7 - http get returns empty

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, angular-http, angular7

I am trying to create my project from scratch in ASP.NET CORE with Angular (SPA template). I've created a basic API & form but unable to fetch the data while I am receiving the data in Network -> Response. Here's my code

API Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
        var res = Json(UsersBAL.GetAll());
        return res;
}
```

Angular Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService } from '../../Services/users.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehicle-form',
  templateUrl: './vehicle-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vehicle-form.component.css']
})
export class VehicleFormComponent implements OnInit {
  users: any;
  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
this.usersService.getUsers().subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.users = data;
  console.log("Users : ",data);
 },
  error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
//console.log("Users : ",this.users);
 }
}
```

Angular Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {
  api_url = 'http://localhost:58508/api/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getUsers() {
return this.http.get(this.api_url + 'Users')
.pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()))
.pipe(
  tap(_ => console.log('fetched users')),
catchError(this.handleError('getusers', []))
);
}
  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

  // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
  console.error(error); // log to console instead

  // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
  console.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

  // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
  return of(result as T);
};
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove this line `.pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()))` from get method. `HttpClient` converts it to json() by default

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `map(res => res.json())` in `HttpClient`. It assumes JSON by default and parses it immediatelly for you.

So just return this in the service:

```
getUsers() {
  return this.http.get(this.api_url + 'Users')
    .pipe(
      tap(_ => console.log('fetched users')),
    catchError(this.handleError('getusers', []))
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line `.pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()))` from `get` method.

`HttpClient` gives the `json` response data by default.

```
return this.http.get(this.api_url + 'Users')
// .pipe(map((response: any) => response.json())) -- not required
.pipe(
  tap(_ => console.log('fetched users')),
catchError(this.handleError('getusers', []))
);
```

Comment: How does your response look like? if you do `tap(data => console.log(data)),` after removing `map`

Comment: same...empty array

Comment: Do you see your response in network tab on browser console?

Comment: getusers failed: Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error

Comment: That's not the pure JSON object. Its an array what you are returning. JSON Object should start with `{`. What you could do is return your data something like `{respData: ['Your actual array data']}`. And then map it like `.pipe(map((response: any) => response['respData']))`

Comment: problem is with access-control-allow-origin

Comment: I dont think. Because you are already getting the response data there.

Comment: Yes...it is confirmed...I've just added chrome plugins for Cors & I started getting data. Now, do you know how can I add CORS in my project